# How can I instantiate and display a Form using only the name of the Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I want to display a grid on a form showing all forms in my project. The user will double-click on a row in the grid to display the form they wish to run. I will then take the name of the form and display.

Normally when I display a form I do the following:

```
MemberEditForm form = new MemberEditForm();

if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   // do something if the user did not cancel the form
}
```

So how do I do the same thing if the name of the form "MemberEditForm" is stored in a variable called formToDisplay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var formType = Type.GetType("YourNameSpace.YourForm");

if (formType != null)
{
    using (var form = ((Form)Activator.CreateInstance(formType)))
    {
        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes you're storing the fully qualified name of each `Form` in your grid, and that all the items are of type `Form` (and not other controls).